# Multiple DB Context vs UnitofWork with Repository Pattern while using dependency injection

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, dbcontext, unit-of-work

I am working on an application with multiple modules. I created tables for different modules under different schema in same database and all user related tables in the default schema. I feel like more confused after reading more about dbcontext, unit of work and repository pattern. I started creating one dbcontext and realized a logged in user need few number of tables but by calling the constructor, it bring everything into memory. Later I thought of creating multiple dbcontexts, but I have to include user related tables in all dbcontexts.

As a third option, I start working with unitofwork and repository pattern. Many articles were telling it is just another abstraction on top of EF with DBContext and DBSet. I still continued working and realized that I will have hundreds of repositories and once I add all of them into unitofwork and call the constructor, again everything will be loaded into memory. I am totally confused on which approach best suits for my need. Each controller need only the specific tables repositories and user tables repositories for the CRUD operations, but by doing above steps, will it cause performance issues?

My unitofwork is as below

```
using DemoApp.Core;
using DemoApp.Core.Repositories;
using DemoApp.Persistence.Repositories;

namespace DemoApp.Persistence
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly DemoAppContext _context;
        public UnitOfWork(DemoAppContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            Ones = new OneRepository(_context);
            Twos = new TwoRepository(_context);
        }
        public IOneRepository Ones { get; private set; }
        public ITwoRepository Twos { get; private set; }

        public int Complete()
        {
            return _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And the controller

```
using DemoApp.Core;
using DemoApp.Core.Domain;
using DemoApp.Persistence;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace DemoApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        public HomeController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var result = _unitOfWork.Ones.GetAll();
            return View(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're overly worried about "loaded into memory". Adding tables to a context doesn't fetch the data for those tables. Think of it as adding some definition, but no data is loaded until you explicitly load it.

Answer (score 0):

Having a single, large context will not load entities into memory on construction, but it will resolve the entity mappings which can take a few seconds in very large contexts for the first load.  Bounded contexts suit very large systems where you can split off related entities, or keep "heavy" or time sensitive entities separate from the main use context.

I use a pattern with bounded contexts that uses an attribute typed to the Context in question to mark which entity type configurations apply to what context. This accommodates using smaller, read-only suited entity definitions. I'd only really recommend this for very large entity sets though. By utilizing deferred execution and .Select() expressions to pull just the data needed when it's needed, using multiple, bounded entity declarations isn't typically needed.

The argument for using Unit of Work & Repository patterns is primarily around enabling unit testing. I do not recommend using Generic repositories (repository per entity) but rather utilizing a Repository pattern much in the way you would utilize a Controller pattern. Each repository serves an area of an application with methods to retrieve, create, and delete entities relevant to that area. Tying a repository to a single entity leads to a lot of boiler-plate code, or generic operations that don't apply to all entities equally. It makes your code less flexible and ultimately harder to read. In most cases you should be utilizing the relationships mapped out between entities, so a single repository can manage retrieving and acting upon all relevant entities for a particular screen for example rather than shifting between lots of different repositories to try and load related data.  I use the DbContextScope UoW pattern by Mehdime as it facilitates both read/write and read-only scopes across repositories/helpers, and negates the need to inject a dbcontext/UoW wrapper into the repositories. This enables having multiple UoW scopes in a request vs. scoping a DbContext/UoW instance to a request or manually messing around with lifetime scopes if your container supports that.  In any case it's worth having a look at as an option. Mehdime's implementation is for EF 6.x, while there are forks available for EF Core.